# While Cloning opportunity i dont want two fields to get cloned

Tags: apex, visualforce, trigger

On opportunity i have two fields : **Primary Campaign Source** and **Funded Services** fields, I dont want these both fields to get cloned while cloning an opportunity.

apex code for this?

Comment: Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour], this forum is not a free code on demand service. If you happen to have tried to write the code on your own, make sure you incldue it in your post alongisde a clear description of what doesnt seem to be working and what you need help with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Salesforce Classic

You don't need apex code for this if you're using the default clone feature on opps.

Click the Clone button on your opportunity. Then look at the URL. Should be something like the following:

> https://gnerb-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/00661000002BJxJ/e?clone=1&retURL=%2F00661000002BJxJ

[Then get the ID of your custom fields](https://www.google.com/search?q=sfdc%20get%20id%20of%20custom%20field&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS768US768&oq=sfdc%20get%20id%20of%20custom%20field&aqs=chrome..69i57j0.4040j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

Lastly, youll create a button on opp. Name it "clone" and set the URL to the same URL you grabbed before. Update the URL with some variables and add your field Ids and remove the base URL and voila:

```
/{!Opportunity.Id}/e?clone=1&retURL=%2F{!OpportunityId}&XXXFIELDID=&XXXFIELD2ID=
```

### Apex

There's a bunch of ways to accomplish this.

1. Create a URL button that links to a VF page. Pass the Opp id as a parameter and completely customize the clone feature
2. Use a method similar to the URL hacking method but populate an "is cloned" field. In your before insert trigger, if isCloned == true, erase those fields
3. 2 but with a process builder/workflow without code

### Sample clone code in apex VF Controller

```
Id oppId = ApexPages.CurrentPage().getParameters().get('oppId');
// Only pull in fields you want to clone (exclude the 2 you don't want)
Opportunity oppToClone = [SELECT /*FieldsToClone*/ FROM Opportunity WHERE Id = :oppId];
oppToClone = oppToClone.clone(false, true, false, false);
insert oppToClone;
```

Comment: Url hacking method worked for me but for the Standard lookup field like "Primary Campaign Source" how to add it to the URL